# How to set a Ansible extra variable to answer a pause prompt in a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

We use an Ansible playbook for running a few commands like `version_get`, `device_status` on the target machine. Intentionally we have restricted `reboot` option from being executed. But occasionally, we would like to automatically answer the `yes` prompt by setting some variables in the `--extra-vars` option.

A simple representation of our playbook minimized to run on localhost.

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
   - name: Confirm Execution
     pause:
       prompt: "You are about to execute a '{{cmd}}' command on the device. Enter 'yes' to proceed"
     register: pause_result
     run_once: True
     when: not (cmd|regex_search('(get|status)'))
   - meta: end_play
     when: pause_result.user_input|default('yes') != 'yes'
```

I know I can add `reboot` as part of the existing `get|status` list, but I don't want to do that, because I want the users exercise special precaution when running it. So with the current code as above, if I run `reboot` I'm left with a prompt like

```
$ ansible-playbook loc.yml  -e 'cmd=reboot'
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Confirm Execution] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
[Confirm Execution]
You are about to execute a 'reboot' command on this device. Enter 'yes' to proceed:
```

I just know how to set a variable to automatically answer this prompt. Tried passing `echo yes |` to the playbook and seeing an error as

```
$ echo yes | ansible-playbook loc.yml  -e 'cmd=reboot'

[WARNING]: Not waiting for response to prompt as stdin is not interactive
```

I also tried to pass the `--extra-vars` as below but none of them seemed to work

```
-e 'cmd=reboot {"pause_result": "yes"}'
-e 'cmd=reboot pause_result=yes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use an other var and condition the prompt to this one. Some lines of code being more expressive than a long speech:

1. The playbook

   ```
   ---
   - hosts: localhost
     gather_facts: no

     tasks:
       - name: Confirm Execution
         pause:
           prompt: "You are about to execute a '{{cmd}}' command on the device. Enter 'yes' to proceed"
         register: pause_result
         run_once: True
         when:
           - not (cmd | regex_search('(get|status)'))
           - not (skip_confirm | default(false) | bool)

       - meta: end_play
         when: pause_result.user_input | default('yes') != 'yes'

       - name: dummy task to see if end of play was effective
         debug:
           msg: "In real world, I would play {{ cmd }}"
   ```
2. Example calls:

   ```
   $ ansible-playbook test.yml -e cmd=reboot
   $ ansible-playbook test.yml -e cmd=reboot -e skip_confirm=true
   ```

If you do not want to introduce a new var, you can use the existing one but that will still require a modification of your current playbook.

The when clause of your prompt should become:

```
when:
    - not (cmd | regex_search('(get|status)'))
    - pause_result is not defined
```

And the call:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml -e cmd=reboot -e "pause_result={user_input: yes}"
```

Comment: Great! Yes I had already thought about this. But isn't there any other way to do this without modifying the playbook at all? i.e. setting vars to modify the `pause_result.user_input` directly

Comment: Well you can, but that would need to modify the playbook anyway.... to not prompt when this var is already set. (i.e. `pause_result is not defined`). So having to modify anyway, I personally like a more intuitive var to use.

Comment: I just edited and added an alternate solution without introducing a new var. Meanwhile, that still needs playbook modifications and the command line is much less readable when you call.

Comment: Thanks for showing the extra option. This is really useful